# Changing object property while storing it in list

Tags: c#

lets say i have class with a lot of redundant properties and i want to store them in list, dictionary or whatever

```
public class Foo
{
 public Bar Bar1 {get;set;} 
 public Bar Bar2 {get;set;}
 public Bar Bar3 {get;set;}
 public Buzz Buzz1 {get;set;}
 public Buzz Buzz2 {get;set;}
 public Buzz Buzz3 {get;set;}


public void UpdateObject(Buzz newValue)
{
 var dict = new List<KeyValuePair<Bar, Func<Buzz >>>()
       {
               new KeyValuePair<Bar, Func<Buzz>>(this.Bar1 ,()=>this.Buzz1),
               new KeyValuePair<Bar, Func<Buzz>>(this.Bar2 ,() => this.Buzz2 ),
               new KeyValuePair<Bar, Func<Buzz>>(this.Bar3 ,() => this.Buzz3 )
       };

 foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                var value = item.Value.Invoke();
                value = newValue;
            }
        }
}

}
```

of course `value` is changed but Foo's Buzz1/2/3 property is not. How can i store some kind of reference to object's property in list, get this item and change object's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the key value pairs with a key and a setter, store a key, a getter, and a setter:

```
List<Tuple<Bar, Func<Buzz>, Action<Buzz>>
```

`Action<Buzz>` is a lambda that takes a new value for that `Buzz` as a parameter.

```
var dict = new List<Tuple<Bar, Func<Buzz>, Action<Buzz>>
   {
        new Tuple<Bar, Func<Buzz>, Action<Buzz>(this.Bar1 ,()=>this.Buzz1, x => this.Buzz1 = x),
        // ...etc...
   };
```

Not sure why you're doing this, but that'll work.

If it were me, instead of a `Tuple` *or* `KeyValuePair`, I'd write a `ThingReference<T>` class that takes the two lambdas, and store those in a `Dictionary<Bar, ThingReference<Buzz>>`.